# Connecting Windows 8 App with Skydrive and Uploading File issue in c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, onedrive

```
 async  private void uploadtosky_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient();

       LiveLoginResult log = await auth.LoginAsync(new List<string> { "wl-basic", "wl.skydrive", "wl.signin" });

       if (log.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
       {
           LiveConnectClient uploadcl = new LiveConnectClient(auth.Session);
           LiveOperationResult up = await uploadcl.BackgroundUploadAsync("me/skydrive", heading.Text, samplefile, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);

       }                
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Oops ! something went wrong while trying to connect");
        msg.ShowAsync();
    }



}
```

When I execute the snippet the `messagebox` showing `Oops ! something went wrong while trying to connect`. My computer is connected to the internet and on clicking the button for uploading, I get a sign in page to live account in the Windows 8 app. However I guess it can't login to the account and so the exception occurs. Any idea to overcome this problem?

Comment: Modify your catch in order to be able to see the exception message:

`catch(Exception o) { MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(o.Message); msg.ShowAsync();}`

and post the message.

Comment: Thank you sir for replying . I found out the mistake . I missed out a scope called wl.skydrive_update .

Comment: Good :). Then please answer your own question and mark it as a valid answer, that way other people with your same problem will be able to find the answer quickly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer finally . Actually there is a  need to replace auth.Session as log.Session ( in the line `LiveConnectClient uploadcl = new LiveConnectClient(auth.Session);` ) and add a scope called wl.skydrive_update in `LiveLoginResult log = await auth.LoginAsync(new List<string> { "wl-basic", "wl.skydrive", "wl.signin" });`

Thats it !

Answer (score 0):

How big is your file? Is it larger than 300MB? I remember that large files have some problems with uploading.

Comment: so I'm out of ideas atm :) But i'll check it later for you

Comment: thank you sir . if i didn't handle the exception the debugger says that it is a LiveAuthException and asks to refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826541.aspx#term_package_identity) for configuring and resolving the problem . If you can figure out something from this kindly assist me .

Comment: found the answer finally . actually i need to replace auth.Session as log.Session and add a scope called wl.skydrive_update . thats it ! done .